# How can I pass multiple value by select in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, object

I need to pass multiple value by using onChange when I select the option, but I can not select single option . it select whole objects .
Here is my code .

```
const test = [{id:1, name:'test, value:{x:10}}]

  <Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children" >
    {test.map(item =>(
    <Option value={item.id, item.value}>{item.name}</Option>

))}   
  </Select>
```

is there an alternative solution to fix this problem

Comment: check this one plz https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/JbbEzX?editors=0010

Comment: I need to two value by using option , i can pass single value

Comment: Which select you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-select you can add isMulti common props to enable multiple selection for your option , please refer: https://react-select.com/props

BTW, react-select default use value label match, you have to remap for your case

```
const options = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test1', value:{x:10} },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2', value:{x:20} },
]  

<Select
    ... // other code
    isMulti
    getOptionValue={option => option.value.x}
/>
```

It support multiple select , sample link : [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-8xs3g)

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom select instead of select.
add multiple values in "eventKey" and on select handler you will find that value array.

```
import { ButtonToolbar,DropdownButton,MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";




<ButtonToolbar className="snap-fitness-wrapper">
    <DropdownButton
        title={this.state.selectedFacilityName}
        onSelect={this.onSelectFacility}
        id="snap" >
    {
        this.state.facilities.map(facility => (
        <MenuItem
            key={facility.facilityId}
            eventKey={[facility.facilityId, facility.name]}
            value={facility.facilityId}
        > {facility.name} - {facility.facilityId}{" "}
        </MenuItem>
        ))
    }
    </DropdownButton>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

Comment: I also think it would be dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
const test = [{id:1, name:'test, value:{x:10}}]

<Select
multiple
showSearch
style={{ width: 200 }}
placeholder="Select a person"
optionFilterProp="children" >
{test.map(item =>(
<Option value={item.id, item.value}>{item.name}</Option>
))}   
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using `antd for select` and want to get the object properties inside `handleChange` of `select`.

A simple method would be to send the `id` or other parameter and get the object through that.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Select } from "antd";

import "./styles.css";

const { Option } = Select;
const test = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", value: { x: 10 } },
  { id: 2, name: "test2", value: { x: 11 } },
  { id: 3, name: "test3", value: { x: 12 } }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange = id => {
    const clickedOption = test.find(item => item.id === id);
    const value = `${clickedOption.id}, ${clickedOption.value.x}`;
    console.log(value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          placeholder="Select a person"
          optionFilterProp="children"
        >
          {test.map((item, index) => (
            <Option value={item.id} key={index}>
              {item.name}
            </Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way of doing this can be like this:

```
let options = test.map(item => {
  return <option value={item.value} onClick={(item) => this.yourhandlerfunction(item)}>item.name</option>
})
render(){
  return(
    <Select>
      {options}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass a second variable in `onChange=((e) => this.handleChange(e, item.value)` property

```js
const handleChange = (event, itemValue) => {
    console.log(`id: ${event.target.value}, value: ${itemValue}`)
}

const test = [{id:1, name:'test', value:{x:10}}]

<Select
    multiple
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, item.value)}
>
    {test.map((item) =>(
        <Option key={key} value={item.id}>{item.name}</Option>
    ))}   
</Select>
```

Comment: "onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, item.value)}" this would result in a ReferenceError as item.value is not defined outside of map() scope.